# Replaced text in multiple documents in notepad++. How do i undo them all?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I used the 'replace All in All opened documents option' to replace them all at once and saved all documents with ctrl + shift + s

I still have notepad++ open since the change occurred and it has not been closed since then, so i hope it is still possible. The reason i want to undo them all at once is because i do not know which documents the changes occurred in, since not all documents contained the string that was replaced. Thank you

Comment: As you've saved it I don't think that would be possible in notepad++. Hopefully you've backup and you can restore previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have notepad++ open you will hopefully be able to hold down ctrl+z to undo changes.
You have to do this for each file, tab1 hold down ctrl+z untill all changes undone, save. tab2 hold down ctrl+z untill all changes undone, save. and so on..

Comment: This will revert changes in files not affected by the global change, as said in OP: "i do not know which documents the changes occurred in, since not all documents contained the string that was replaced"